# Activerecord collection iterate: error if not read field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, iterator

I have strange behavior when I try to iterate collection of AR model:

```
@created = QueueOnline.new
Order.online.created.to_a.each do |o|

  # p o.customer
  @created.try_to_offer_translators(o)
end
```

Where:

```
class OrderQueue
  def try_to_offer_translators(order)
    if order.sticky_translator?
      process_sticky_translator(order)
    return
  end
  #byebug #if I stop this and get order.customer - all work fine
  translators_for_order(order).each do |translator|
    offer_to(order, translator)
  end
end
```

If I don't stop or get value from `order.customer` it will be `nil`, but if I stop or do simple call `p order.customer` underlying functions will work fine.

PS: if I take single item `order`, put it in array - it's working fine too.

```
[order].each do |o|
  @created.try_to_offer_translators(o)
end
```

================

UPDATE:
I understood my problem is because don't loaded relation (customer).
If I change to:

```
Order.eager_load(:customer).online.created
```

It will work fine. But I always thought if object a didn't load it will be loaded when it necessary.

Comment: are `online` and `created` supposed to be filters?  Could you show your `Order` model?  Why did you find `to_a` was requried?  A collection of records from a filter will respond to the `each` method.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, yes it's filters(scopes). I use `to_a` for test if problem from ActiveRecord.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting problems from ActiveRecord.  What class do you see if you type `Order.online.created.class` ?  It should be ActiveRecord Relation.

Comment: Problem maybe is in STI:  order has two relation - customer and translator, but both it is a User and uses one table.